# Wicket 6 - Prevent jQuery call scrolling page to top using AjaxCallListener

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, wicket, wicket-6

Within my Wicket (6.27) page, I have an AjaxLink. Within this AjaxLink I use an AjaxCallListener to call some javascript to display and his a spinner div that fills the page. The Javascript is a simple addClass/removeClass call.

When calling this addClass/removeClass the page scrolls to the top. This is undesirable. I know that the addClass / removeClass is to blame for the scrolling as when I remove these, everything is fine.

How do I prevent the page from scrolling on link click in my situation?

Code snippets below:

The link in html:

```
<a wicket:id="do-things-link" class="do-things-link" href="javascript:void(0)">Do The Things</a>
```

The link in the code:

```
final AjaxLink link = new AjaxLink(WICKET_ID_THE_LINK)
{
    @Override
    protected void updateAjaxAttributes(AjaxRequestAttributes attributes) {
        super.updateAjaxAttributes(attributes);
        attributes.getAjaxCallListeners().add(new GlobalSpinnerListener());
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target)
    {
        doSomething(target);
    }
};
```

The AjaxCallListener - GlobalSpinnerListener class (where customScriptReference is my js code, shown after):

```
@Override
public CharSequence getBeforeHandler(Component component) {
    return ";displayGlobalSpinner();";
}

@Override
public CharSequence getCompleteHandler(Component component) {
    return ";hideGlobalSpinner();"
}

@Override
public void renderHead(Component component, IHeaderResponse response) {
    ResourceReference jqueryReference =
            Application.get().getJavaScriptLibrarySettings().getJQueryReference();
    response.render(JavaScriptHeaderItem.forReference(jqueryReference));
    response.render(JavaScriptHeaderItem.forReference(customScriptReference) );
}
```

And the js code:

```
function displayGlobalSpinner() {
    $('#global-page-activity-indicator').addClass('on');
}

function hideGlobalSpinner() {
    $('#global-page-activity-indicator').removeClass('on');
}
```

The global spinner is found in the html under other content in the body:

```
<div id="global-page-activity-indicator" class="am-loading-spinner">
```

And the css for that class is this:

```
/* Absolute Center Spinner */
.am-loading-spinner {
   display: none;
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 9999;
   height: 2em;
   width: 2em;
   overflow: visible;
   margin: auto;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
 }

.am-loading-spinner.on {
  display: block;
}

/* Transparent Overlay */
.am-loading-spinner:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

Comment: I don't really see a reason why this JS code would scroll the page. Is this all you do in the JS functions ?

Comment: That is all they do as shown. I have added more information about how the spinner is declared in the html and it's related css classes (if that has anything to do with it)

Comment: Why don't you use the AjaxIndicatorAppender / IAjaxIndicatorAware approach from Wicket? (See also: https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/master/wicket-extensions/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/extensions/ajax/markup/html/AjaxIndicatorAppender.java)

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into that and give it a go when the issue becomes higher priority (again).

Answer (score 1):

What do you do exactly on `doSomething(target);` ? It could be you add some component to the target, it will be new rendered and replaced in markup, then you get a "top scrolled page".

Comment: I think, unfortunately, that may be it. We're using ShieldUI charts and at some points in the code 'reinitialize' them, since the chart components cannot be replaced or removed/added as their js scripts go all funny. This may be the actual reason for my pain.